# Error while creating a table from the values of two tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to sql. I was just trying to create and store data into a table from the values of two tables

1 st table has UserName.
 2nd table has password.

So, I have written a sql query with gets both values from two tables and display it in a single table.

```
      Create table tablename as
select
       T1.username,
       T2.Password
from
       Table1.T1,
       Table2.T2
where
       T1.UserId = T2.UserId;
```

Here in both tables UserId  is common.

I am getting error while executing this statement.

The error is InCorrect Syntax. Error is near SELECT statement.

Can you help me Please,

Thanks in advance

Comment: The correct syntax for this in `tsql` is `Select ... Into tablename from ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support `CREATE TABLE AS`.  Instead, use `INTO`:

```
select T1.username, T2.Password
into tablename
from Table1.T1 join
     Table2.T2
     on T1.UserId = T2.UserId;
```

Notice that I also fixed your `join` syntax.  Although the use of commas in the `FROM` clause does not generate an error, it should.

Comment: If i want to store the output into new table. How to write a query for that?

Comment: above is the method, did you notice `into tablename` part?

Comment: Yaa, I forgot to refresh the DB. That why i cannot see the new table.